# managing fonts in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

Is there a better way to manage fonts in Illustrator instead of the default drop-down? I am on CS6 and Windows7

I have several hundred fonts and I wish there was a more intuitive way to browse through my fonts.

Any suggested add-ons or extensions ?

Answer (score 5):

Font managers help

- [Font Agent Pro](https://www.insidersoftware.com/FA_pro_plus.php) (My preference)
- [Extensis Suitcase](http://www.extensis.com/suitcase-fusion/)
- [Font Explorer](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/)

But they don't alter the menus within Illustrator.

There's really no way to change the font menus within the app.

Illustrator CC has implemented several features regarding font searching and display in the menus. While I absolutely detest the whole Adobe *rental* thing that is the "Creative Cloud", and I dislike answering with "upgrade", if this is a critical issue for you, that may be a course of action you want to look into.

Comment: oh good, I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks the Cloud "rental" concept is a bunch of hooey.